# Excel / Libre Office Calc: Taking the average of a multiplication

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I have three rows in Libre Office

```
Weight:       0,2  0,2  0,3  0,3
Max. Points:  2    3     4   5
Points:       2    ---   4   4      0,74
```

For each column that `Points` is divided by `Max. Points` and then multiplied with `Weight`, which itself is divided by the sum of all `Weight`s. However, if a cell in `Points` is text (not a number), it should be discarded in the calculation and not be set to 0. Here, it should be as if there was no second column. Finally I want to take the average.

I got this far:

```
SUMPRODUCT(K23:N23;POWER(K22:N22;-1);K21:N21/SUM(K21:N21))
```

But this is not calculating the average, but a percentage. Also I was not able to integrate the fact that it ignores text in `Points`. One way to go about this would be to set the `Weight` for the text-`Points` to 0. I could use `IF` and `ISNUMBER`, but the later does not except rows, but only cells. I am not sure how this should look like.

For example (this time with US decimal notation)

```
Weight:       0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
Max. Points:  2    3     4   5
Points:       1   ---    3   4      0.74375
```

here is what I want:

```
0.74375 = 1/2*(0.1/(0.1+0.3+0.4)) + 3/4*(0.3/(0.1+0.3+0.4)) + 4/5*(0.4/(0.1+0.3+0.4))
```

Comment: Should 0,2 be 0.2 instead?  Also what is meant by "which itself is divided by the sum of all Weights"  -- What is "itself"?

Comment: @JimK: 1) Depends on the country ;-). 2) itself is `Weights`. Please compare that sentence of mine with the formula I build below. This is how far I got. The next sentence ("Howeve, if a cell...") is what I have not been able to include.

Comment: It looks like your new example has a mistake. The weight for column E is `0.4`, not `0.3`. After the correction, the result should be `0.74375`.

Comment: your example calculation is wrong, please double check it (last part `4/5*(??0.3??/(0.1+0.3+??0.4??))`)

Comment: @JimK: You were right. I corrected it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: I corrected it - that's what you mean, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula currently is:

`Sum(points / maxPoints * weights / sum(weights))`

However you can transform it to this form without changing the output:

`Sum(points / maxPoints * weights) / sum(weights)`

With this you can easily calculate:

`SUMPRODUCT(K23:N23;POWER(K22:N22;-1);K21:N21)/SUMIF(K23:N23;">=0";K21:N21)`

### Update:

If you have many rows with "point", then you need to combine absolute and relative references to calculate:

`SUMPRODUCT(K23:N23;POWER(K$22:N$22;-1);K$21:N$21)/SUMIF(K23:N23;">=0";K$21:N$21)`

Comment: This seems to be working, but I am not sure, how: What is happening to the second column in my example? Is the text considered to be equal 0 and thus eliminating the second column from `SUMPRODUCT(K23:N23;POWER(K22:N22;-1);K21:N21)` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how libreoffice manage that, I think multiplication with a text would return error, and SUMPRODUCT just ignores it.

Comment: By "just ignores it" you mean that the whole column is ignored,right? These logical reasons are why @JimK added ISNUMBER...?

Comment: "ignores it" means the whole result of the multiplication (0.2*3*"-") is ignored, not just the text.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what we both mean: It's like the column was not there. How can I transfer the formula to a lot of cells? The first two rows stay just as they are, but since I have many students, I have many `Points` rows. So `K23:N23` needs to change to `K24:N24` etc. in the formula, but `K21:N21` and `K22:N22` needs to stay just as it is.

Comment: then you need to use absolute references for max points and weights, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is what I came up with:

```csh
=SUMPRODUCT(K23:N23,POWER(K22:N22,-1),K21:N21/SUM(K21:N21),ISNUMBER(K23:N23)) / SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(K23:N23))
```

I added the `ISNUMBER` check as you requested.  However it did not seem to make any difference -- `SUMPRODUCT` already ignored column L because it produced an error.

Also, to get the average, I divided by `SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(K23:N23)`.  This simply counts the numerical values, of which there are 3 in this example.

The end result of this formula is `0,247` which is simply `0,74` / `3`.

**EDIT**:

Here is a formula that produces `0.74375` as expected for the second example:

```csh
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:E3,POWER(B2:E2,-1),B1:E1/SUMPRODUCT(B1:E1,ISNUMBER(B3:E3)),ISNUMBER(B3:E3))
```

Comment: I am not sure that is what I want. I got the idea to make the second example above to explain what I mean.

Comment: Yes, that second example makes it clearer because it shows the desired outcome.  It helped me see what went wrong in my first attempt.  It was including the weight from the second column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works and I would like to except it too. Mate's answers is shorter, so I chose it for now (unless you can give a convincing argument, why your's is functionally better).

Comment: No problem.  That's what upvoting is for.